# Terminal client which allows sending raw bytes?

Tags: serial

Is there an application like putty, that would allow me to type in raw bytes to send over serial?

Comment: good question, but I'm with Majenko. fwiw, there is an olde but goode utility called commhex ..

Comment: related: ["How to transmit single Hex value serial data in Putty ...?"](http://superuser.com/questions/759398/how-to-transmit-single-hex-value-serial-data-in-putty-using-alt-code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/): under the Send tab, you can send either ASCII or raw bytes, the latter either decimal, hex, or escape sequences.

[image]